# angular interceptor route <a href="#"> to 404 page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I use href="#" as a placeholder in html, however I found that angular could not recognize it and route to the 404 page with the following config in module. How to solve this problem?

```js
.config( function myAppConfig ( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$httpProvider ) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise( '/404' );
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
    })
```

Comment: is the problem with href="#"

Comment: Angular has specific handling for links with `href="#"`. What about if you link to some non-existent route instead? Just change to use `href="/placeholder"` instead of `href="#"`.

Comment: @GregL for non-existing route, it will link to 404 page. I also use some third-party ui libraries and by default they set href="#".

Comment: @harish Yes, you are right. I just wonder # should be part of html standard, it is quite normal to use #id to navigate in one html. Why angular just intercepts that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because angular uses # as a sign for angular routing, and here has three options to solve this problem.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10105#issuecomment-63450792

Answer (score 0):

the problem is because of `href="#"`. there are many questions around this problem on SO.

the issue is by default all the routes are prefixed with #, so angular does try to route even if `href="#"`

though for angular routes better way is to use ng-href and put only valid router `href="#"`.

I am not aware of any way to get around this problem, apart from remove the href tag.